# Using joda time to seed and then compare

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I am trying create a seed point for Joda-Time. What I am trying to achieve is that I will provide a seed `datetime` in Joda-Time, this should generate two different random `datetime` such that `datetime1` is before than `datetime2` and this `datetime` will generate values only for that specific hour of seed point.

e.g.

```
time- 18:00:00  followed by date-2013-02-13

Random1 - 2013-02-13 18:05:24 

Random2 - 2013-02-13 18:48:22
```

The time is received from one DB and the date is selected by the user. I need the two times randomly generated in the specified format
You can see that only the minutes and seconds will change, nothing else will be modified.

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do what you want. If it is possible that the minutes or seconds in your seed time are not zero, you should add [.withMinuteOfHour(0)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withMinuteOfHour%28int%29)[.withSecondOfMinute(0)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withSecondOfMinute%28int%29) after the `.parseDateTime(inputDateTime)` method call.

```java
import java.util.Random;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class RandomTime {

DateTimeFormatter inputFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTimeFormatter outputFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

public TwoRandomTimes getRandomTimesFromSeed(String inputDateTime) {
    DateTime seed = inputFormat.parseDateTime(inputDateTime);
    Random random = new Random();
    int seconds1 = random.nextInt(3600);
    int seconds2 = random.nextInt(3600 - seconds1);

    DateTime time1 = new DateTime(seed).plusSeconds(seconds1);
    DateTime time2 = new DateTime(time1).plusSeconds(seconds2);
    return new TwoRandomTimes(time1, time2);
}

public class TwoRandomTimes {
    public final DateTime random1;
    public final DateTime random2;

    private TwoRandomTimes(DateTime time1, DateTime time2) {
        random1 = time1;
        random2 = time2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Random1 - " + outputFormat.print(random1) + "\nRandom2 - " + outputFormat.print(random2);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RandomTime rt = new RandomTime();
    System.out.println(rt.getRandomTimesFromSeed("18:00:00 2013-02-13"));
}
}
```

In this solution the first random time is indeed used as the lower bound for the second random time. An alternative solution would be to just get two random dates and then sort them.

Comment: Incredible job, thank you man the idea of getting time2 by subtracting second1 never hit my mind. Thank you very much.

Comment: @chettyharish My pleasure. :) Just check the implementation for corner cases and off-by-one errors. For example, the random times may be same, especially if the first time is 18:59:59.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with something like the following:

```
final Random r = new Random();
final DateTime suppliedDate = new DateTime();
final int minute = r.nextInt(60);
final int second = r.nextInt(60);

final DateTime date1 = new DateTime(suppliedDate).withMinuteOfHour(minute).withSecondOfMinute(second);
final DateTime date2 = new DateTime(suppliedDate).withMinuteOfHour(minute + r.nextInt(60 - minute)).withSecondOfMinute(second + r.nextInt(60 - second));
```

Assuming that `suppliedDate` is the date from your database. Then you generate two new times with random minutes and seconds based off of your seed time. You will also guarantee that the second time is after the first time by changing the bounds of the random number calculated.